# Double the item sometime

Tags: c#

I wanted to add a code that will let the add button add to Stock if the item brcode already exist I wrote the code but the first time the user do the add button it works and it adds it to the stock but when the user press it again it add to the stock + add new item with the same values. its really annoying I have been working all the day to find a way to do it on my own (I am still learning).
What am I missing

this is the code

```
private void btnadd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int addedstock;
        string stock = "";
        cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Products WHERE Item_Code = @Code and Item_Stock = @Stock", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Code",codeadd.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Stock", stockadd.Text);

        con.Open();        
        int result = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
        con.Close();
        if (result >= 1)
        {                


            DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();
            DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("An Item with BrCode already exists. Do you with to add to the stock?", "Item Manager", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
            if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Products", con);
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                if (reader.Read())
                {
                    stock = Convert.ToString(reader.GetInt32(4));
                }
                con.Close();

                addedstock = Convert.ToInt32(stockadd.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(stock);




                cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Products SET Item_Stock = @Stock WHERE Item_Code=@Code", con);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Stock", addedstock));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Code", codeadd.Text));
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                dt.Clear();
                sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * From Products", con);
                dt = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dt);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

            }
        }

        else if (result != 1)
        {
            cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Products Values(@Item_Name, @Item_Price, @Item_Code, @Item_Stock, @Item_ExpDate)", con);
            SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[5];

            param[0] = new SqlParameter("@Item_Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
            param[0].Value = nameadd.Text;

            param[1] = new SqlParameter("@Item_Price", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
            param[1].Value = priceadd.Text;

            param[2] = new SqlParameter("@Item_Code", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
            param[2].Value = codeadd.Text;

            param[3] = new SqlParameter("@Item_Stock", SqlDbType.Int);
            param[3].Value = Convert.ToInt32(stockadd.Text);

            param[4] = new SqlParameter("@Item_ExpDate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
            param[4].Value = Convert.ToString(expdateadd.Text);

            con.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.AddRange(param);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            dt.Clear();
            sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * From Products", con);
            sda.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Something went wrong", "Item Manager", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

    }
```

thank you

Comment: Least helpful title evar. Please read [ask], especially the part about writing a title. Also update your tags to provide what technology you're using. That's probably Winforms, but could be ASP.NET WebForms too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are checking not only if there exists a product with the same code, but with the same stock, whenever the stock in the DB is not the same as the one you want to add the query will fail:

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Products WHERE Item_Code = @Code and Item_Stock = @Stock", con);
```

If you have added two units and then you try to add one more (per example), that query will return `0` and you will add a duplicate item.

To correct that simply remove the stock quantity from the query:

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Products WHERE Item_Code = @Code", con);
```

Also, I would create a unique index on `Item_Code` to avoid duplicates and also that will allow you to do an `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` to directly in one query create or update the product.